# How to select sub-terms in taxonomy when creating content?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

In creating a document management system I've created a taxonomy vocabulary with this structure:

```
Accounting
  Client 1
  Client 2
Client 1
  Contacts
Client 2
  Contacts
  Correspondance
Leasing
  Client 1
  Client 2
```

Then, in my Document content type I've created a term reference field called Tags which uses autocomplete. The autocomplete part works great, but I don't know how to differentiate Accounting:Client 1 from Leasing:Client 1 from Client 1 (parent level). When loading a new document, is there a way to reference these terms properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Simple Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) is the module for the job.

> Simple hierarchical select defines a new form widget for taxonomy fields to select a term by "browsing" through the vocabularies hierarchy.

Just change the widget-type of field **Tags** to **"Simple hierarchical select"** after you install the module. This [guide](https://www.webwash.net/using-simple-hierarchical-select-module-in-drupal-7/) might come handy if you're running 7.

Comment: That did it - exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [multilevel autocomplete module](https://www.drupal.org/project/multileveltagautocomplete). If that help you.